# Select multiple containers with text and trim first 150 characters

Tags: javascript

I have to select with Javascript multiple posts called blog-post and take all the text and trim it for the first 150 characters but I don't know how to resolve it. 
From the dom, I'm selecting all the blog-post with the `querySelectAll()` and then I'm trying to find a solution to trim those characters.

An example of the snippet I'm trying here

```js
function trimCharacters() {
    let blogPost = document.selectQueryAll(".blog-post");
    for (let post in blogPost) {
        blogPost.push(blogPost.textContent.substring(0, 150));
    }
}

trimCharacters();
```

```html
 <div class="blog-post">
     <h2 class="blog-post-title">Sample blog post</h2>
     <p class="blog-post-meta">January 1, 2014 by <a href="#">Mark</a></p>

     <p>This blog post shows a few different types of content that’s supported and styled with Bootstrap.
         Basic typography, images, and code are all supported.</p>
     <hr>
     <p>Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis <a href="#">dis parturient montes</a>, nascetur ridiculus
         mus. Aenean eu leo quam. Pellentesque ornare sem lacinia quam venenatis vestibulum. Sed posuere
         consectetur est at lobortis. Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum.</p>
     <blockquote>
         <p>Curabitur blandit tempus porttitor. <strong>Nullam quis risus eget urna mollis</strong>
             ornare vel eu leo. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
     </blockquote>
     <p>Etiam p
     </p>
 </div>
  <div class="blog-post">
     <h2 class="blog-post-title">Sample blog post</h2>
     <p class="blog-post-meta">January 1, 2014 by <a href="#">Mark</a></p>

     <p>This blog post shows a few different types of content that’s supported and styled with Bootstrap.
         Basic typography, images, and code are all supported.</p>
     <hr>
     <p>Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis <a href="#">dis parturient montes</a>, nascetur ridiculus
         mus. Aenean eu leo quam. Pellentesque ornare sem lacinia quam venenatis vestibulum. Sed posuere
         consectetur est at lobortis. Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum.</p>
     <blockquote>
         <p>Curabitur blandit tempus porttitor. <strong>Nullam quis risus eget urna mollis</strong>
             ornare vel eu leo. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
     </blockquote>
     <p>Etiam p
     </p>
 </div>
  <div class="blog-post">
     <h2 class="blog-post-title">Sample blog post</h2>
     <p class="blog-post-meta">January 1, 2014 by <a href="#">Mark</a></p>

     <p>This blog post shows a few different types of content that’s supported and styled with Bootstrap.
         Basic typography, images, and code are all supported.</p>
     <hr>
     <p>Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis <a href="#">dis parturient montes</a>, nascetur ridiculus
         mus. Aenean eu leo quam. Pellentesque ornare sem lacinia quam venenatis vestibulum. Sed posuere
         consectetur est at lobortis. Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum.</p>
     <blockquote>
         <p>Curabitur blandit tempus porttitor. <strong>Nullam quis risus eget urna mollis</strong>
             ornare vel eu leo. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
     </blockquote>
     <p>Etiam p
     </p>
 </div>
```

Will appreciate to see a solution for my problem with an explanation of what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: inside your cycle `post.textContent = post.textContent.substring(0, 150);`

Comment: It's not `selectQueryAll` or `querySelectAll`, it's `querySelectorAll()`. If you open up your console, you will see that error message.

Comment: also, you might want to push `post`, not `blogPost`

Comment: I shared the jsfiddle with you to check it however I get substring is not defined erorr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`document.selectQueryAll` is not a function. You probably meant `document.querySelectorAll`.

The rest of your code is almost correct, except that you don't reference the individual elements when you loop through the selected nodes. I would prefer to use the forEach method rather than a for loop. See below:

```
function trimCharacters() {
    let blogPost = document.querySelectorAll(".blog-post");
    blogPost.forEach(d => {
        d.textContent = d.textContent.substring(0, 150);
    })
}

trimCharacters();
```

Comment: The issue is that I get substring is not defined

Comment: @Jakub Make sure that you are not calling your function before the whole document is loaded.

Comment: @Jakub In your original post you were calling substring on blogPost.textContent, which will be undefined as blogPost is a nodeList. In my answer it's called on the element within the nodeList, which has a string value for textContent. substring is a string method, so it will only be defined when used on a string.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution will break HTML markup inside a post. `blogPost` it's `HTMLCollection` not an `array`. You can't push something inside it. Your blog post contains a title and metadata that should be saved as I understood. To cut off the needed number of characters, it needs to go through all children elements and check if an element content isn't bigger than the limit and push it in a new content array that would replace the current content. By default, I add title and metadata in the new array and remove it from children that we will cut off. Sorry for my bad English...

`[].slice.call()` it's just a trick to use the array methods on HTMLCollection.

```js
function trimCharacters(charsToCut) {
    let blogPost = document.querySelectorAll(".blog-post");
    
    blogPost.forEach( post => {
    
      let limit = charsToCut;
      const tagsToSkip = ['HR', 'IMG']; 
      const newContent = [].slice.call(post.children, 0, 2);
      
      [].slice.call(post.children, 2)
        .forEach(postBody => {
        
           if(limit === 0) return;
           
           if(tagsToSkip.indexOf(postBody.tagName) !== -1) return;
           
           if (postBody.textContent.length <= limit) {
              limit -= postBody.textContent.length;
              newContent.push(postBody);
              return;
           }
           
           if(postBody.textContent.length > limit) {
              postBody.textContent = postBody.textContent.slice(0, limit - 3) + '...';
              limit -= postBody.textContent.length;
              newContent.push(postBody);
              return;
           }
           
      });
      
      post.replaceWith(...newContent);
    });
    
}

trimCharacters(150);
```

```html
<div class="blog-post">
     <h2 class="blog-post-title">Sample blog post1</h2>
     <p class="blog-post-meta">January 1, 2014 by <a href="#">Mark</a></p>

     <p>This blog post shows a few different types of content that’s supported and styled with Bootstrap.
         Basic typography, images, and code are all supported.</p>
     <hr>
     <p>Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis <a href="#">dis parturient montes</a>, nascetur ridiculus
         mus. Aenean eu leo quam. Pellentesque ornare sem lacinia quam venenatis vestibulum. Sed posuere
         consectetur est at lobortis. Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum.</p>
     <blockquote>
         <p>Curabitur blandit tempus porttitor. <strong>Nullam quis risus eget urna mollis</strong>
             ornare vel eu leo. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
     </blockquote>
     <p>Etiam p
     </p>
 </div>
  <div class="blog-post">
     <h2 class="blog-post-title">Sample blog post2</h2>
     <p class="blog-post-meta">January 2, 2014 by <a href="#">Mark</a></p>

     <p>This blog post shows a few different types of content that’s supported and styled with Bootstrap.
         Basic typography, images, and code are all supported.</p>
     <hr>
     <p>Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis <a href="#">dis parturient montes</a>, nascetur ridiculus
         mus. Aenean eu leo quam. Pellentesque ornare sem lacinia quam venenatis vestibulum. Sed posuere
         consectetur est at lobortis. Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum.</p>
     <blockquote>
         <p>Curabitur blandit tempus porttitor. <strong>Nullam quis risus eget urna mollis</strong>
             ornare vel eu leo. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
     </blockquote>
     <p>Etiam p
     </p>
 </div>
  <div class="blog-post">
     <h2 class="blog-post-title">Sample blog post3</h2>
     <p class="blog-post-meta">January 3, 2014 by <a href="#">Mark</a></p>

     <p>This blog post shows a few different types of content that’s supported and styled with Bootstrap.
         Basic typography, images, and code are all supported.</p>
     <hr>
     <p>Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis <a href="#">dis parturient montes</a>, nascetur ridiculus
         mus. Aenean eu leo quam. Pellentesque ornare sem lacinia quam venenatis vestibulum. Sed posuere
         consectetur est at lobortis. Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum.</p>
     <blockquote>
         <p>Curabitur blandit tempus porttitor. <strong>Nullam quis risus eget urna mollis</strong>
             ornare vel eu leo. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
     </blockquote>
     <p>Etiam p
     </p>
 </div>
```